# How to refactor two select queries on RSForm submission data?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, rsform, pivot

I was wondering if anyone could help me JOIN multiple queries into one query. Currently, these 2 blocks of code retrieve information from the DB. I am using the "Sourcerer" plugin to add custom PHP code in my custom module.

However, the full query is much too long, and I need to reduce the size considerably. After a certain amount of queries, the page just doesn't load at all.

I will post two queries I need to have joined as an example.

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->getQuery(true);

$db->setQuery("SELECT `SubmissionId`, `FieldValue`, `FormId` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Status1\" AND `FieldValue` = \"Pending\" AND `FormId` = 28");
$results = $db->loadColumn();

$db->getQuery(true);
$db->setQuery("SELECT `FieldValue` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Container1\" AND `SubmissionId` IN ('".implode("', '", $results)."') ORDER BY `jos_rsform_submission_values`.`SubmissionId`"); 

$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($result as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $data) { 
        echo $data."<br />"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'll try and write more details for the question. I literally just need to put those 2 queries into one query. That is all. I'll add some more details though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I believe the mySQL query to be with (1,2,3) substituted in for your imploding of results because I wanted to check the mySql syntax of it.  I don't have time to convert into PHP right now, but wanted to try to help.  If it doesn't work, let me know in comments and I will try to adjust:
`SELECT a.FieldValue as Container, b.FieldValue as ContainerType
FROM (
    SELECT FieldValue 
    FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
    WHERE FieldName = "Container1" 
       AND SubmissionId IN (1,2,3)) as a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FieldValue
    FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
    WHERE FieldName = "containertype1" 
        AND SubmissionId IN (1,2,3)) as b
on a.SubmissionId = b.SubmissionId
ORDER BY a.SubmissionId;`
I had to remove the tick marks to get StackExchange to format correctly, but I would suggest converting your code to use $db->quote and $dbquotename instead anyway: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase
https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply mate!! I will give it a go and let you know :)

Comment: I know this is 2 months late, but I was wondering if you could post the PHP code for this?

Comment: I'm pretty slammed this week but will take a look when I get some time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your queries can certainly use refactoring.  Using two separate calls on the same table is asking MySQL to do needless extra work.

To convert your queries into plain English, you want to:

- create a result set of `containertype1` values sorted by `SubmissionId`
- for each `SubmissionId` from `FormId` `28`
- including only submissions that contain a `Status1` value of `Pending`.

The cleanest, most direct way to perform this task is with a "pivot" technique.

Raw Query (untested):

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'containertype1' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END)
FROM `#__rsform_submission_values`
WHERE FormId = 28
GROUP BY SubmissionId
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'Status1' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END) = 'Pending'
ORDER BY SubmissionId
```

`GROUP BY` creates "aggregate data" for each unique `SubmissionId`. Extracting specific details from within this collection of consolidated rows requires specialized calls (e.g.`MAX(CASE...)`).

The `HAVING` clause requires SubmissionIds to contain a row with a `FieldName` of `Status1` and a `FieldValue` value of `Pending`. This relies on the fact that your submission_values table does not allow a SubmissionId to have 2 or more `Status1` rows.

For every qualifying SubmissionId, the result set will provide the value that is stored with `containertype1`. If the qualifying SubmissionId does not have a `containertype1` row, a `NULL` value will be provided as the default (you could change `NULL` to `No Container Type` if you wanted).

PHP/Joomla Syntax (untested):

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'containertype1' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END)")
    ->from("#__rsform_submission_values")
    ->where("FormId = 28")
    ->group("SubmissionId")
    ->having("MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = " . $db->q("status") . " THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END) = " . $db->q("pending"));

// echo $query->dump();  // uncomment if you want to confirm the rendered query
try {
    $db->setQuery($query);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($db->loadColumn());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // never show getMessage() to public
}
```

If you would like to see this technique in other contexts, here are some other pivot solutions that I have posted:

- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23921/12352
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24320/12352