# How to get Custom Fields related to Joomla Content?

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, custom-field, jdatabase, pivot

I want to know how they get the values of custom user fields within Joomla articles. This is to contribute ideas and ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two custom fields in your database.  In the `#__fields_values` table:

- `1` relates to the custom field called "genre"
- `2` relates to the custom field called "somethingelse"

To use pure sql to extract a single article's custom values and assign meaningful column aliases you can use a technique called a pivot -- it effectively "rotates" the alignment of the data 90° so-to-speak.

```
$userId = JFactory::getUser($this->item->created_by)->id;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select([
                  "MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS genre",
                  "MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS somethingelse"
              ])
            ->from("#__fields_values")
            ->where("item_id = " . (int)$userId);
            ->group("item_id")
echo $query->dump();  // display the rendered query
$db->setQuery($query);
echo "<pre>";
var_export($db->loadObject());  // output the data
```

From this snippet, the following info will be presented.

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS name,MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 4 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS location
FROM abcde_fields_values
WHERE item_id = 1
GROUP BY item_id
```

---

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
  'genre' => 'Sci-Fi',
  'somethingelse' => 'Some random text',
))
```

The result set is a single row of associative keyed values.  If a particular value doesn't exist for an article, `null` will be assigned as the fallback value.

Not using a pivot will mean your result set will have *n* rows with one value in each row.

While less compelling when dealing with a single article, this coding technique is a clean, direct, and powerful way to package multiple articles (just be sure to generate the result set with `loadObjectList()`).

Use the `MAX(CASE(...` syntax in the `SELECT` as many times as you like to continue grabbing more data that may exist in the "aggregrate" generated by `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can obtain the values directly.

```
$userId = JFactory::getUser($this->item->created_by)->id;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('value');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__fields_values'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('item_id')." = ".$db->quote($userId));

$db->setQuery($query);
$fields = $db->loadColumn();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    echo $field;
}
```