# How to collect multi-row data from #__fields_values and assign specific aliases for each value in the result set?

Tags: mysql, jdatabase, sql, alias, pivot

I have the following (working) query to get `name`, `username` and the `value` of a custom field:

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select name and username from USERS table and value from FIELDS_VALUES table.
// Define USERS table as ju
// Define FIELD_VALUES as jfv and match id and item_id to perform an inner join
// Set condition
// Set Order as ascending

$query
    ->select(array('ju.username', 'ju.name', 'jfv.value'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__users', 'ju'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__fields_values', 'jfv') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('ju.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('jfv.item_id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('jfv.value') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('C%'))
    ->order($db->quoteName('ju.username') . ' ASC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load results as a list of objects in an array
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($results);
```

This is used to display the `name` and `username` of a user together with `door`, `floor` and `staircase` in an apartment building. In this case all people from `staircase` "C".

The table `#__fields_values` looks like this for user `48`:

```
field_id | item_id | value |
============================
2        | 48      | 5     |
============================
3        | 48      | C     |
============================
4        | 48      | 2     |
============================
```

In the above table:

- the `door` value is `5`
- the `staircase` value is `C`
- the `floor` value is `2`

My problem is that my output looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => C1 [name] => NameOfTheGuy [value] => C
    )...
```

but what I need is to have the `floor` value, not the `staircase` value.

Is it possible to assign an alias based on the value inside a column (let's say `jvf.staircase` if `jfv.field_id = 3`)?
Or is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: My intuition tells me that you are seeking [a pivot](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24331/12352), however after reading your question a few times, I'm not fully following your logic with the sample data.  I'd like to see your exact desired result set for your sample data.  To make things REALLY easy for volunteers (especially ones that provide support predominately from their mobile phone -- like me), you can provide a db-fiddle.com demo for us to play with / test on.

Comment: I am happy to post an answer after work once I understand your exact requirements.  Here's something that I mocked up on the train... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ms4n8QxymVdKsXS7fJ9hec/0  If this is getting close to what you want, please let me know and I'll post a proper answer with Joomla's query builder syntax.

Comment: Yes, that absolutely works and you fully nailed it, even on the train! Is this a pivot as you've been mentioning eralier? I'll remember to post a db-fiddle next time, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw Pivot Query

```
SELECT ju.username,
       ju.name,
       MAX(IF(jfv.field_id = 2, jfv.value, NULL)) AS `door`,
       MAX(IF(jfv.field_id = 3, jfv.value, NULL)) AS `staircase`,
       MAX(IF(jfv.field_id = 4, jfv.value, NULL)) AS `floor`
FROM `#__users` AS ju
INNER JOIN `#__fields_values` AS jfv ON ju.id = jfv.item_id
GROUP BY ju.username ASC, ju.name
HAVING MAX(IF(jfv.field_id = 3, jfv.value, NULL)) LIKE 'C%'
```

Possible Result Set:

```
| username | name  | door | staircase | floor |
| -------- | ----- | ---- | --------- | ----- |
| FollaKY  | Folla | 5    | C         | 2     |
```

---

[View Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ms4n8QxymVdKsXS7fJ9hec/2)

PHP/Joomla Code (<s>untested</s> tested):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$juUsername = $db->qn("ju.username");   // Cache this (D.R.Y.)
$juName     = $db->qn("ju.name");       // Cache this (D.R.Y.)
$jfvFieldId = $db->qn("jfv.field_id");  // Cache this (D.R.Y.)
$jfvValue   = $db->qn("jfv.value");     // Cache this (D.R.Y.)

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select([
        $juUsername,
        $juName,
        "MAX(IF($jfvFieldId = 2, $jfvValue, NULL)) AS " . $db->qn('door'),
        "MAX(IF($jfvFieldId = 3, $jfvValue, NULL)) AS " . $db->qn('staircase'),
        "MAX(IF($jfvFieldId = 4, $jfvValue, NULL)) AS " . $db->qn('floor')
    ])
    ->from($db->qn('#__users', 'ju'))
    ->innerJoin($db->qn('#__fields_values', 'jfv') . ' ON ' . $db->qn('ju.id') . ' = ' . $db->qn('jfv.item_id'))
    ->group([
        "$juUsername ASC",  // declare the sorting order here
        $juName
    ])
    ->having("MAX(IF($jfvFieldId = 3, $jfvValue, NULL) LIKE " . $db->q("C%"));

// echo $query->dump();  // uncomment if you want to confirm the rendered query
try {
    $db->setQuery($query);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_export($db->loadObjectList());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // never show getMessage() to public
}
```

Explanation in steps:

1. Join the `users` table to the `fields_values` table.  This is a one-to-many relationship for each `users` row.  Using `INNER JOIN` is different from `LEFT JOIN` because `INNER JOIN` will omit `users` rows that do not have at least one `fields_values` row to relate to.
2. To prevent multiple rows for the same user, `GROUP BY` is implemented.  This creates "aggregate data" (in other words, a cloud|mass|cluster|pile of `fields_values` data specific to that user) for each user.
3. To determine which users qualify for the result set based on a row-specific value in `fields_values`, you will need to perform a comparison on the aggregate data.  The `HAVING` clause will check all of the aggregate data. If an aggregate row does not have a `field_id` of `3` then it is assigned a value of `NULL` (within the scope of this sub-process). If the `field_id` is `3`, then the original `value` is maintained. This creates (unless you have a row with `field_id` of `3` and a `value` of `NULL` -- in which case every `value` is `NULL`) a lone non-NULL value to be "picked up" by `MAX()` -- apply your comparison logic on this lone value.
4. Now that all of the joining, grouping, and filter are finished, it is time to fix up the actual result set.  At this point, there is still "aggregate data" being sent to the `SELECT` clause, but the result set cannot be delivered with "aggregate data" in it (in other words, the rows need to be flattened).  Using the same *filter&max* technique as in the `HAVING` clause, manually write each specific column that you wish to generate for each row in the result set -- assign whatever column alias you wish after `AS`.  Done.

---

Now there are a few ways to code this up...

- "D.R.Y." (found as comments in my script) stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself".  This is a best practices technique which helps to keep your script lean and clean and it spares php having to perform the same task multiple times.
- Sometimes you will see `CASE-WHEN` statements instead of `IF` statements inside of `MAX()` these are logically interchangeable.
- Result set sorting can be done inside of the `GROUP BY` clause in this scenario, but can also be done with an `ORDER BY` clause.
- **NONE** of the `$db->qn()` calls are *actually* necessary for this query because none of the table or column names have monkeywrenching characters or are on [the list of MySQL Reserved Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).  As you can see, all of those concatenations and quoting calls reeeeeeally bloat the syntax and make reading and finding typos much harder.  If this was my project, I'd be inclined to remove all of the backtick-generating calls and I would also remove quoting calls on static strings like `C%` ...but this is all a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Many apologies @FollaKY my untested snippet had too many typos.  I got a chance to test my updated snippet on my localhost and it's definitely all good now.

Comment: Hi, and thanks once more for this! I know a year passed since then, but I hadn't got a chance to come back to this subject earlier. So now I'm trying to get this to work, but apparently I'm not able enough to get it to the point where it is giving me the results I'm expecting.

Comment: Do you want to post a new question with specific details so that I can assist further? A [mcve] (minimal complete verifiable example)with a db fiddle demo is usually all I need.

Comment: It's still the same topic though... Wouldn't that be regarded as being duplicate? :-) Let me explain, probably it's a very small thing.  On my prod page, I load an object list and then individually echo the results where I need them in my table : <?php echo $results[0]->name; ?> I know that's useless effort, but I needed something that works. It would be more elegant to generate the table programmatically. I'm understanding from your code that this should work as well (at least for name and username), but nothing shows up...

Comment: But I can see you coming... where is $results defined... *facepalm*

Comment: I'm still not coming forward on this one. When I add '$results = $db->loadObjectList();' and 'print_r($results);' at the end of your code to see the results of the query, I only get 'Array()' as a result. As if the query isn't returning any results. I uncomment where suggested to show the query that is actually ran.

Comment: Okay.  Let's attack this thing.  Please create a [mcve] so that I can replicate your issue and tell me exactly what you expect @Folla

Comment: Ok, cool. Here's the db fiddle [link]https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ms4n8QxymVdKsXS7fJ9hec/4 for starters. The PHP code I'm using is the one you posted up here. I only added the two lines mentioned earlier.

Comment: The PHP code I'm using is the one you posted up here. I only added the two lines mentioned earlier. I'm only tracking staircase A instead of C, so  $db->q("A%")... It is inside a custom HTML module. The plan is, once there is a populated array, to create an hmtl table programmatically. Right now I simply call data from a static table.

Comment: @Folla If I understand you correctly, the dbfiddle is working as desired?  The problem is in your querying syntax.  Please show me the chunk of code that you are using to query and generate the result set array as a 3v4l.org demo link -- it should be easy for me to spot the issue. (sorry, I was at the gym last night when I commented, then I spent the rest of my night with my family ...away from the computer)